# Can we download the binary releases from github using Jfrog remote repo?

Tags: artifactory, jfrog-cli, jfrog-xray

I am trying to download the packages of grafana from github releases using our Jfrog Artifactory instance.

The github url is :- https://github.com/grafana/k6/releases/download/v0.42.0/k6-v0.42.0-linux-amd64.tar.gz

Inorder to achieve this , I create a generic typr of remote repo (named as grafana-generic
) in jfrog Artifactory by pointing the remote url to https://github.com.

I referred this solution forn [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46060675/artifactory-download-github-release-using-remote-repository), But it didnt help.

The url which I tried to download the package is as below

https://myrepo/artifactory/grafana-generic/grafana/k6/releases/download/v0.42.0/k6-v0.42.0-linux-amd64.tar.gz

Error is getting as below

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "status": 404,
      "message": "Item grafana-generic-cache:grafana/k6/releases/download/v0.42.0/k6-v0.42.0-linux-amd64.tar.gz does not exist"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to fetch a VCS Release you can use the [Download a VCS Release REST API](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-DownloadaVCSRelease) command